# PostgreSQL finding difference between last three login dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I would like to take the last three login dates for each customer, and find those customers who have more than 4 days between their before before last login (login3) and last login (login1).

The "activity" table contains:

- user_id
- login_date in DATETIME format, however the time is always 00:00:00
- (and some other not related to the issue fields)

I tried several queries but none of them is working properly.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? If >=8.4 you could have a solution involving [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html).

Comment: I think its 9.1. Can you please explain more in details, Im a new Postgre user.

Comment: @Boris: It's `PostgreSQL` or `Postgres` for short. No such thing as `Postgre`. If you are not sure about the version, ask the server with `SELECT version();`

Comment: `before last login (login3)` is supposed to be 3rd-last login? And how would you deal with users that have only 1 or two logins, yet?

Comment: @Erwin Brandsteller, thanks for the remarks. The version is 9.1.1, in the current task I dont have any information about that particular case.

Comment: I quote the [official Postgres site here](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/): *We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor release for whatever major version is in use.* This would currently be 9.1.5.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution that could work with PostgreSQL 8.3 and later using arrays.

Generate test data. Vary the second parameter of `generate_series()` to add more activity records:

```
create table activity (id serial primary key, user_id integer, login_date timestamp);
insert into activity (user_id, login_date)
  select * from
  (
   select round(random()*10)::integer as user_id, ('2012-01-01'::date + (round(random()*300))* '1 day'::interval) as login_date
   from
   (select generate_series(1,1000)) foo
  ) fooger order by login_date;

select * from activity;
```

Query out the desired data:

```
--show last three login dates per user:
select user_id, login[1] as login1, login[2] as login2, login[3] as login3
from
(
 select user_id, array_agg(login_date) as login from
 (select * from activity order by user_id,login_date desc) foo
 group by user_id
)  foo;

--shake out those who haven't been visiting frequently enough
select user_id, login[1] as login1, login[2] as login2, login[3] as login3, (login[1] - coalesce(login[3],login[2],login[1]))::interval as diff
from
(
 select user_id, array_agg(login_date) as login from
 (select * from activity order by user_id,login_date desc) foo
 group by user_id
)  foo
where login[1] - coalesce(login[3],login[2],login[1])  > '4 days'::interval;
```

Comment: Thanks, Joshua Berry, Im gonna test it as soon as i have "create" and "insert" permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I used and simplified the setup provided by @Joshua:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE activity (id serial primary key, user_id integer
                                                 , login_date timestamp);
INSERT INTO activity (user_id, login_date)
SELECT * FROM  (
   SELECT round(random()*10)::int AS user_id
        , ('2012-01-01 0:0'::timestamp + random() * interval '365 days') AS ts
   FROM   generate_series(1,1000)
   ) g
ORDER  BY ts;
```

You can use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html), available since PostgreSQL 8.4:

```
SELECT user_id, login1, login3, (login1 - login3) AS time_span
FROM   (
   SELECT user_id, login_date
         ,first_value(login_date)      OVER w  AS login1
         ,COALESCE(lead(login_date, 2) OVER w 
                  ,lead(login_date)    OVER w) AS login3 
   FROM   activity
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY login_date DESC)
    ) x
WHERE  login_date = login1
AND    (login1 - login3) > interval '4d';
```

It's easier to read IMO, but in a quick test @Joshua's query was ~ 30 % *faster*.

- Users with only one entry never qualify.
- For users with only two entries, the 2nd last is used instead of the 3rd last.

That aside, if the time part of your timestamps is always `00:00:00` you may want to consider using a [`date` column instead of `timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: @Boris: Added a hint concerning data types.

Comment: (for bonus points) IMHO you could repalce the temp table activity by a CTE.

Comment: @wildplasser: That's just the setup for the test case ... one could replace the subquery with a CTE .. for bonus points, though. :) However, sorry to be a spoilsport, subquery *is* faster.

Comment: Yes, now I see. I thought it was a pre-aggregation thingy. You still could. (but you won't earn the bonus points !)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness: NAIVE version (query plan shows three separate subplans for the 3 CTE's; which is bad) (a recursive CTE should also be possible ;-)

```
WITH l3 AS (
        SELECT a3.id, a3.user_id, a3.login_date
        FROM   activity a3
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                FROM activity nx
                WHERE nx.user_id = a3.user_id
                AND nx.login_date > a3.login_date
                )
        )
, l2 AS (
        SELECT a2.id, a2.user_id, a2.login_date
        FROM   activity a2
        JOIN l3 ON l3.user_id = a2.user_id AND l3.login_date > a2.login_date
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                FROM activity nx
                WHERE nx.user_id = a2.user_id
                AND nx.login_date > a2.login_date
                AND nx.login_date < l3.login_date
                )
        )
, l1 AS (
        SELECT a1.id, a1.user_id, a1.login_date
        FROM   activity a1
        JOIN l2 ON l2.user_id = a1.user_id AND l2.login_date > a1.login_date
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                FROM activity nx
                WHERE nx.user_id = a1.user_id
                AND nx.login_date > a1.login_date
                AND nx.login_date < l2.login_date
                )
        )
SELECT l1.user_id
        ,l1.id AS ii1, l1.login_date AS d1
        ,l2.id AS ii2, l2.login_date AS d2
        ,l3.id AS ii2, l3.login_date AS d3
FROM l1
JOIN l2 ON l2.user_id = l1.user_id
JOIN l3 ON l3.user_id = l1.user_id
WHERE l3.login_date - l1.login_date > '4 days'::INTERVAL
        ;
```